React native build "Evaluating settings" step taking forever
Print of terminal
I am building a mobile app with react native and typescript, until now it was working fine, but yesterday I tried to start it up with react-native run-android and it just doesn't go through this "Evaluating Settings" step, once I tried to let it running and it was 40 minutes in this step, it also happens for any other command from gradle like ./gradlew clean
I tried removing android/.gradle deleting node_modules, yarn.lock and Users/user/.gradle and starting it up again but it did not help.

Solved it. After trying lots of times to remove cache from gradle and yarn and not working I realized the problem was likely to be on some code or configuration I changed. I looked in git history for a commit in which the project was working and rolled back to it to see if I can still run it and it worked, then I found what was the exactly the commit that broke the build and looked for the files changed in it, I found out that I had accidentally updated react-native version from ^0.74.2 to ^0.75.1 I also had added redundant types for react navigation and removed it (although I believe it had nothing to do with it). After rolling back the version, deleting node_modules, yarn.lock, android/.gradle, Users/user/.gradle and running it all again it worked. Its weird that gradle does not give any error messages for using the incorrect react-native version, I also ran npx react-native doctor and did not showed anything wrong with my setup.

I have the same problem but when I upgraded from ^0.74.3 to ^0.75.2,
The gradlew is evaluating, but no progress.
The debug console shows the below message over and over again.
2024-09-02T01:00:10.325+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-09-02T01:00:10.325+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-09-02T01:00:10.326+0300 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.


If it isn't important for you to have the version 0.75.2 I suggest you just roll back to the previous. If it is necessary then good luck, I searched a lot for this problem and found no one talking about it to the point I decided to make an account in stack overflow and post the problem. If you find a solution though please come back here and explain it, maybe it will help someone with the same problem in the future.

try use this
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/
I also had an upgrade from @0.73.6 to @0.75,
this worked for me.

Thank to dioo1461, I double check my files in UpgradeHelper and now it works!
In my case I forgot to update settings.gradle and gradle-wrapper.jar files after upgrading react-native to version ^0.76

You probably just need a stronger PC to run it
